# Information regarding XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java

I came across the class [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) today.
I searched in Google regarding its usage but did not find any satisfying answer.

Hence can anyone answer the following questions?

1. What is `XMLGregorianCalendar`?
2. What is the usage of this class?
3. How it is different from `GregorianCalendar` or both of them are related?

Comment: The first thing you should do when you find a new class and want to know stuff about it is check the JavaDoc (I linked it in your question). Does that answer your questions? If not, please clarify.

Comment: I have gone through it before posting this question. But still not very clear with the explanation. I just know that its used to represent date and time in XML files. Why its represented differently and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML Schema standard specifies [**very** precise rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) about the functionality and representation of dates in XML. Those rules *don't* match exactly what Javas `Calendar` (or `GregorianCalendar`) uses.

Therefore the `XMLGregorianCalendar` class was introduced, which follows the rules specified by the XML spec.

Answer (score 0):

It is for date/time datafields within XML, defined by the w3c:

> Representation for W3C XML Schema 1.0
>   date/time datatypes. Specifically,
>   these date/time datatypes are
>   dateTime, time, date, gYearMonth,
>   gMonthDay, gYear gMonth and gDay
>   defined in the XML Namespace
>   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema".
>   These datatypes are normatively
>   defined in W3C XML Schema 1.0 Part 2,
>   Section 3.2.7-14.

via http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html